# Face recogniton automatic picture in code

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to setup face recognition with opencv/python on raspbian with the code i placed here. But i actually would like that in the code it automatically takes a picture of someone when the system recognizes a person. And that is safes the image with time/person in a specific folder.

I can't find anything usefull on the internet, maybe you can help me?

Kind regards,

Timo

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import face_recognition
import imutils
import pickle
import time
import cv2

#Initialize 'currentname' to trigger only when a new person is identified.
currentname = "unknown"
#Determine faces from encodings.pickle file model created from train_model.py
encodingsP = "encodings.pickle"
#use this xml file
cascade = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

# load the known faces and embeddings along with OpenCV's Haar
# cascade for face detection
print("[INFO] loading encodings + face detector...")
data = pickle.loads(open(encodingsP, "rb").read())
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)

# initialize the video stream and allow the camera sensor to warm up
print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=-1).start()
#vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

# start the FPS counter
fps = FPS().start()

# loop over frames from the video file stream
while True:
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to 500px (to speedup processing)
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    
    # convert the input frame from (1) BGR to grayscale (for face
    # detection) and (2) from BGR to RGB (for face recognition)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # detect faces in the grayscale frame
    rects = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, 
        minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)

    # OpenCV returns bounding box coordinates in (x, y, w, h) order
    # but we need them in (top, right, bottom, left) order, so we
    # need to do a bit of reordering
    boxes = [(y, x + w, y + h, x) for (x, y, w, h) in rects]

    # compute the facial embeddings for each face bounding box
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
    names = []

    # loop over the facial embeddings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
        # encodings
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "Unknown" #if face is not recognized, then print Unknown

        # check to see if we have found a match
        if True in matches:
            # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
            # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
            # was matched
            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
            # each recognized face face
            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            # determine the recognized face with the largest number
            # of votes (note: in the event of an unlikely tie Python
            # will select first entry in the dictionary)
            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)
            
            #If someone in your dataset is identified, print their name on the screen
            if currentname != name:
                currentname = name
                print(currentname)
        
        # update the list of names
        names.append(name)

    # loop over the recognized faces
    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        # draw the predicted face name on the image - color is in BGR
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 225), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            .8, (0, 255, 255), 2)

    # display the image to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Facial Recognition is Running", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # quit when 'q' key is pressed
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    # update the FPS counter
    fps.update()

# stop the timer and display FPS information
fps.stop()
print("[INFO] elasped time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You already have the image...you named it `rgb`. Why don't you just save it if a face is detected?

Comment: Yes, but i would like it to be automatically saved in a specific folder and i cannot figure out what code i need to use for that. So i have the image yes, but is it possible that in the code it will automatically take a screenshot when it sees someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Imagenode](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagenode), [Imagehub](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagehub), and [Imagezmq](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq), I use them in a security camera system that I use on the RPI, you may be able to adapt them to your needs.  Imagenode only sends a pic to imagehub when motion is detected.  Imagehub does an image classification on pic and tells me if its a dog, cat, car, or person.  Then Imagehub sends me a txt alterting me to motion being detected.  Imagehub then saves the pic locally along with sending it to dropbox so I can view it when I am away from my computer.  Its a very flexible system it may be what you need.

Hope this helps